# Autocorrelation summation identity

Tags: time-series, self-study

Let $X_t$ be a weakly stationary process with mean $\mu$ and autocovariance function $\gamma$.

How do I show that
$$n^{-2}\sum_{i=1}^n  \sum_{j=1}^n cov(X_i, X_j)$$ equals $$ n^{-2} \sum_{i-j=-n}^n (n- |i-j|)\gamma(i-j)$$

Thanks

Comment: The definitions of weakly stationary and autocovariance explain how $\text{Cov}(X_i,X_j)$ can be replaced by $\gamma(i-j)$ in the double sum and the rest is a matter of manipulating those sums to collect common terms.  Where exactly in this process are you stuck?

Comment: Write out a $n\times n$ covariance matrix (with entries $\operatorname{cov}(X_i, X_j)$) and replace each $\operatorname{cov}(X_i, X_j)$ by $\gamma(i-j)$. DO  NOT use letters such as $i$ and $j$ in your matrix; the top left corner should have $\gamma(0)$ in it. _Admire_ each diagonal in the matrix thus created. What is the length of each diagonal (there are $2n-1$ diagonals of varying lengths for you to consider)? What is the _sum_ of the entries on each diagonal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Two Pictures

**I like Dilip's suggestion to admire a matrix**, so I will depict it first for the case $n=5$ as an example:

[image: Autocovariance matrix]

The double sum adds the entries in this table.  There are $5$ ($=n$) values of $\gamma(0)$ along the diagonal, $4$ ($=n-1$) of both $\gamma(1)$ and $\gamma(-1)$ along the super- and sub-diagonal, and so on.

Notice that the arguments to $\gamma$ range from $1-n$ up through $n-1$: there are none with arguments $-n$ or $n$.

To help you admire it, I made it prettier by color-coding entries with common values :-).

---

**Another way to visualize a double sum** is to set up two linear arrays, one for each set of indexes, and match all possible pairs with arrows.  Here, the lower array depicts the collection of first indexes $X_i$ while the upper array depicts the second indexes $X_j$. Each arrow represents the covariance between the corresponding random variables.  Weak stationarity implies the covariances of parallel arrows (from $i$ to $j$, $i+1$ to $j+1$, $i+2$ to $j+2$, *etc.*) are all the same, equal to $\gamma(i-j)$, as shown in the legend at right.  (The color-coding is the same as for the matrix above.)  The double sum is the sum over all arrows, of which (count them) there are $5$ ($=n$) with the value $\gamma(0)$, *etc.*

[image: Graph]